# How to increase root partition in Centos 7

Tags: centos7

So I have root partition in sda2 and I have another disk with partition in sdc1, is it posible to extend the capacity of sda2 using the sdc1? i'm using centos 7.

[image: https://serverfault.com/users/login?ssrc=anon_ask&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fserverfault.com%2fquestions%2fask]

Comment: Hello. "mounting" /dev/sdc1 in a mount point of / (belonging to /dev/sda2) doesn't fit your need?. For example, in your (/etc/fstab) you could create a mount point for the /home directory targeting /dev/sdc1. Like that, all of your user data would be stored in /dev/sdc1 instead of /dev/sda2 (and this "almost" transparently for your system)